# Symfony2/Doctrine and PostgreSQL NOTIFY/LISTEN

Tags: database, postgresql, symfony, notifications, doctrine-orm

I am writing a database application on PostgreSQL that has two parts:

1. GUI - written in Symfony/Doctrine
2. Processing - written in C/libpq

The processing component will process data from a table after it has been inserted by the GUI. However, how does the processing component know there is a change? My default answer would have been to use the PostgreSQL notify/listen commands, as I'm keen to avoid some kind of polling.

Questions:

1. Is there some way that the Symfony application could use the postgresql notify command? Doctrine supports Native SQL selects, but I don't believe this is what I need.
2. Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A native `SELECT` should be entirely sufficient.

While you usually use the `NOTIFY` statement, it's also possible to call the `pg_notify` function for the same effect.

```
SELECT pg_notify('key','payload');
```

Your worker can `LISTEN key;` as normal, and will receive notifications generated this way the same as if `NOTIFY` was used.